# Python - Parsing a specific value from a URL within a line

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I've managed to get my script to print out a line of text based on what is in the line:

```
if "cvename" in line:       
    CVE = list_of_line[4:5]     
    print "The CVE number is ", ' '.join(CVE)       
    print " "
    CVEfile.write("CVE-" + str(CVE) + '\n')
```

which prints out:

```
['http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=1999-0016][Xref']
```

But what I want is just the value '1999-0016'

I'm assuming a regular expression can be used to do this but I don't have much experience in using them. What I've noticed is that the value I want to extract always starts with a year as it is a CVE number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always try to use a more specific approach before using regular expressions. You need to parse an url? Use `urlparse`.

```
import urlparse

u = 'http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=1999-0016'

q = urlparse.urlparse(u).query
values = urlparse.parse_qs(q).get('name')
if values is not None:
    print values[0]
    # prints '1999-0016'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression in this case, yes:

```
re.compile(r'name=(\d{4}-\d{4})')
```

would match any text starting with `name=` followed by two 4-digit numbers. The grouping allows you to extract that number:

```
>>> import re
>>> cve_param = re.compile(r'name=(\d{4}-\d{4})')
>>> cve_param.search('http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=1999-0016][Xref').group(1)
'1999-0016'
```

I do notice that *usually* the CVE number is prefixed by the text `CVE-`; a regular expression that would match both forms would be:

```
re.compile(r'name=(?:CVE-)?(\d{4}-\d{4})')
```

Using a regular expression would allow you to pick out such URLs from a full body of text. If you are using a proper HTML parser on the other hand, I'd recommend parsing the URLs for constituent parts instead.

Comment: the URL is stored within a variable called CVE, so i tried this: cve_param.search(CVE).group(1). but i get the following result: <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x9147d18> instead of the numbers

Comment: Why are you slicing your `list_of_line` list? `list_of_line[4]` would be a single string, instead of a list with a single element. If you don't need a list, don't use a list. :-)

Comment: See my example in the answer; `re.compile()` returns a compiled pattern object; the `_sre.SRE_Pattern` reference you have. You could also use `re.search(r'name=(\d{4}-\d{4})', CVE)` directly. `.search()` returns either `None` (nothing found), or it returns a match object on which you can call `.group(1)` to get the matched first group. Please *do* read the [`re` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to fix your parsing algorithm further, but to get just the value part:

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlparse
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(s).query)['name'][0]
'1999-0016][Xref'
```

Once you fix this bit `CVE = list_of_line[4:5]` the above will give you the expected result.